# Deciphering Acronym in Holy Book

Tags: acronyms

I'm reading an introductory book on kabalistic topics, "Amud Haavoda" from Rabbi Boruch Kosover. At the end of the first part, question--answer, when the author says an original and deep chiddush, he writes

> ואל יראנו נפלאות מתורתו בנל"כ ולאע"י

or

> ודי למבין בנל"כ ולאע"י

or simply

> בנל"כ ולאע"י

Can someone decode the rashei tevot?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bracha derivated from [Yeshayahu 40:29](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%9E_%D7%9B%D7%98)

> ‏[‏בָּרוּך] נֹתֵ֥ן לַיָּעֵ֖ף כֹּ֑חַ וּלְאֵ֥ין אוֹנִ֖ים עׇצְמָ֥ה יַרְבֶּֽה׃
>
> [Blessed be the one who] gives to the weak strength, and to the one
>   with no might, should have his might increased.

Comment: +1 seems to fit. But how do you know this is true?